# Solving Algorithm (Josephus permutation) in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, josephus

Suppose 100 people line up in a circle. Counting from person 1 to person 14, remove person from the circle. Following the count order, counting again and remove the 14th person. Repeat. Who is the last person standing?

I've tried everything to solve this and it seems to not be working with dead loops.

```
<?php
//init array
$array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) { $array[] = $i; }

//start from 0
$pos = 0;
while (count_not_null($array) > 1) {
    //reset count
    $count = 0;
    while (true) {
        //ignore NULL for count, that position is already removed
        if ($array[$pos] !== NULL) {
            $count++;
            if($count == 14) { break; }
        }
        $pos++;
        //go back to beginning, we cant go over 0-99, for 100 elements
        if ($pos > 99) { $pos = 0; }
    }
    echo "set index {$pos} to NULL!" ."<br>";
    $array[$pos] = NULL;
    if (count_not_null($array) === 1) { break; }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";


//counting not null elements
function count_not_null($array) {
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if ($array[$i] !== NULL) { $count++; }
    }
    return $count;
}
?>
```

Comment: What behavior *are* you seeing and why does this not match your expectations?

Comment: if ($array[$pos] != NULL) {
            $count++;
        }

i am already skipping NULL, doesnt consider as count, as NULL is considered to me a person already removed.

Comment: you don't need to loop through the array every time, it would be faster if you had a variable for remaining elements and decremented that after $array[$pos] = NULL; once you have one element remaining break and print it

Comment: @NathanielFord I think the behavior he's seeing is an infinite loop, that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: Isn't this `Josephus problem`? There is a cool script here to solve this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#PHP

Comment: I've tried your approach, with a remaing count var, the problem was storing the actual position

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that the person that gets removed first is the one at index 14 (i.e. the 15th person, since the array is zero-based)

Comment: Another problem: `0 != NULL` is false. You should use strict comparison, `$array[$i] !== NULL`.

Comment: Add  a statement `print "Deleting $pod<br>";` when you set an element to null, you'll see that you delete the same element multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For solving this with as little code as possible and quickest you could do like this:

```
function josephus($n,$k){
    if($n ==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (josephus($n-1,$k)+$k-1) % $n+1;
}

echo josephus(100,14);
```

Here we are using an recursive statement instead, as what you are trying to solve can be defined by this mathematical statement `f(n,k) = (f(n-1,k) + k) % n`
For reading more about this mathematical formula you can see it [here on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this while loop

```
    while ($count < 14) {
        if ($array[$pos] != NULL) {
            $count++;
        }
        $pos++;
        if ($pos > 99) { $pos = 0; }
    }
```

Because you increment $pos even if count is 14 you will end with incorrect values and loop forever. Replace it with this:

```
    while (true) {
        if ($array[$pos] != NULL) {
            $count++;
            if($count == 14) {break;}
        }
        $pos++;
        if ($pos > 99) { $pos = 0; }
    }
```

Also comparing 0 to NULL won't give you the expected results as mentioned by @Barmar, so you can either change the NULL comparison, or start counting from 1

NOTE: This would be way faster if you didn't loop through array every time :D consider using a variable to count the remaining items

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who stumbles across this again, here is a slightly quicker one:

```
function josephus($n){
    $toBin = decbin($n); // to binary
    $toBack = substr($toBin,1) . "1"; // remove first bit and add to end
    return bindec($toBack); // back to value
}
```

Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#Bitwise) solution.